# Is there a way to check that the hardware of one server is the same as that of another?

Tags: hardware, ubuntu-14.04

We have three Ubuntu (trusty) servers taking requests. One of them is having a variety of weird problems that we are trying to find the cause of.

Firstly, we want to rule out hardware differences. So we want to verify that the hardware on all three servers is the same, and that the OS on each sees all the hardware in the same way. Is there a straightforward way to get a summary we can compare from each server? Almost like an md5 checksum of the hardware?

Comment: You don't know what type of hardware you're running on?

Comment: As we're trying to work out a problem that only appears on one out of three supposedly identical servers, it would seem silly to not double check and rule it out. So no. Until we've double checked, I'm going to say we're not certain of what exact hardware each server is running. *Shrug*

Comment: [XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - What are the symptoms exhibited on the problem server?

Comment: I don't see how my question is subject to the XY Problem. I'm asking for a way of listing the hardware on 2 machines so they can be compared. This is not a supposed solution "Y" for problem "X".

Comment: What he means by that is you'd rather post the main problem that led you to believe that different hardware could be the cause for your issue.

Comment: I work with Alex. We know what @ewwhite was asking. The problem is far out of the scope of a question here and if we were to try and ask it, probably stackoverflow would be the place to do it. The question asked was very specific and all we wanted was an answer, not people questioning why we are asking the question. Would he/she have been happy to answer it if Alex had left off the first 2 sentences?

Comment: @LukeCousins I was just trying to be thorough. As you can see, I left an answer with a suggestion on how to acquire this information.

Comment: @LukeCousins It is possible that a lot of us have the XY Problem but fail to look at it. ewwhite was just trying to help the approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try installing the List Hardware package for Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install lshw
```

Run the command

```
sudo lshw -short
```

on all three hardware & compare it using Notepad++ after installing its Compare plugin. This is the best and easiest way I can think of. The command above leaves a lot of detail, of course. If you need it in detail you can leave out the *-short* switch and route the output to a html, xml or txt file as shown below.

```
sudo lshw > hardware.txt
sudo lshw -html > hardware.html
sudo lshw -xml > hardware.xml
```

You can also try using an excel sheet. Depends on what you are comfortable with.

Comment: If you are already using a GNU/Linux machine you can always use `diff`. If the files are too large, hash them.

Comment: Or, if you're running a desktop environment, you can use `meld`, which will do word-diffing, color/highlighting and side-by-side scrolling

Answer (score 4):

The `dmidecode` command is likely already installed. Try this:

> dmidecode -t 1 | egrep '(Manufacturer|Product|Serial)'; dmidecode -t 0
>   | egrep '(Version|Release)'; dmidecode  -t processor| egrep
>   '(Socket|Version)'

I'd be interested in seeing the output...

However, if you're having stability issues, hardware differences probably aren't the issue. Is this a hosting environment? If so, they're likely using lower-end or hand-assembled (*cough... [Supermicro](http://www.supermicro.com/index.cfm)*) equipment. You may want to see if there are any messages in the kernel ring buffer (`dmesg | tail`) on the problem server.

The type of equipment in use by these providers typically doesn't have any form of hardware monitoring available. You may have out-of-band options like IPMI, but it's not as tightly integrated with the sensors/components on generic hardware.